# Sketch a graph that satisfies the following conditions using derivatives

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, graphing-functions

> Plot the graph of a function that satisfies the following conditions:
>
> - $\operatorname{dom}(f)=\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.
> - $f'(x)<0$ in $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$.
> - $f''(x)>0$ in $(-\infty,-2)$ and $(0,+\infty)$.
> - $f''(x)<0$ in $(-2,0)$.
> - $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=-\infty$.
> - $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=+\infty$.
> - $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=+\infty$.
> - $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$.

---

I have thought about $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$ and $g(x)=-e^{1/x}$ but clearly they do not fit in all conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this look? I think this meets all the requirements. Don't try to come up with a description of a function...just try to draw the requirements [image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of thinking of specific functions that could potentially meet these requirements, why not use the requirements as a guide to start drawing a function?

For example, you know $f(x)$ is decreasing on $(-\infty, 0)$ and that it is concave up from $(-\infty, -2)$ and concave down on $(-2,0)$. It also shoots off to $-\infty$ as you get close to $0$ from the left-hand side. Using these facts, try starting at a point in the third quadrant and sketch what $f(x)$ should look like as $x \rightarrow 0^-$.